# Procedures for boarding a cruise at Miami?

Tags: public-transport, cruising, miami, x-ray-machines

In a few weeks, I will be departing off Miami for a cruise. It it my first time on such an adventure.

- From downtown Miami, how to reach the pier where cruise liners usually pick up passengers? Is there public transit nearby or should I get a cab?
- How far in advance of the sailing time should I show up so that I can clear the boarding procedures?
- What are the usual boarding procedures? Is there a X-ray / metal detector check like at airports? Is there a separate luggage handling?

Comment: I had a rental car that I returned before a cruise in Miami. There was a free transfer from the car rental station to the ship of my choice. After the cruise I took the tranfer back to a car rental station and took another car to continue my journey.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can go by public buses to Port of Miami. I can not give you specific details since I do not know from where you will take the bus. [Google Maps](https://maps.google.com/maps?q=Port+of+Miami,+Africa+Way,+Dodge+Island,+Miami,+FL&hl=en&sll=25.779102,-80.170455&sspn=0.033041,0.066047&geocode=Fe0diQEdzkc3-w%3BFVJIiQEd48I4-yn7GM8mPLTZiDGKO4yur-10wA&t=h&dirflg=r&ttype=now&noexp=0&noal=0&sort=def&hq=Port+of+Miami,+Africa+Way,&hnear=Dodge+Island&z=17&start=0) will offer a great help. Please note if you take a bus you will have to walk from the bus station to the terminal which is a ~10 minutes walk. It is advised to go by car and get dropped off at the terminal.

You need to reach the terminal minimum of 2 hours in advance, as mentioned in the [official site of Port of Miami](http://www.miamidade.gov/portmiami/cruise-safety-security.asp). Anyway different cruise companies have different rules:

> Passengers should arrive at least two hours prior to departure. Check with your cruise line for the latest embarkation/debarkation information.
>
> Security procedures, prohibitions and documentation requirements vary by cruise line or destination. Contact your cruise line for details about the specific requirements and restrictions for your itinerary.

Regarding pre-boarding and luggage procedures, since you will pass a TSA check as mentioned in the official website then you will pass a metal detector and your luggage will pass X-ray scanners just like any airport.

Answer (score 2):

I know my answer is a little late to the party but I've found it sometimes cheaper $100 per person to fly into Ft. Lauderdale and just take a van ride down from that airport to the cruise port.

Comment: You're right, the flights to Fort Lauderdale airport are more cheaper, and is just 25 min from Miami port